# Was sagt Markus Gürne zum Abschied in "Börse vor Acht"?

Tags: phrase, spoken-language, listening-comprehension

Ich schaue mir ganz oft die Sendung "Börse vor Acht" im Ersten an. Besonders schätze ich Markus Gürne wegen seiner gehobenen Sprache.

Leider ist es mir misslungen, seinen Ausdruck zum Abschied zu verstehen, den er immer verwendet. Z. B. heute (https://www.daserste.de/information/wirtschaft-boerse/boerse-im-ersten/videosextern/wirtschaft-im-osten-deutschlands-hat-aufholbedarf-100.html) ist er aufgetreten, und hat noch einmal in den letzten Sekunden gesagt, was sich anhört wie

> ...wie immer an dieser Stelle, Ihnen allen einen schönen Abend, **wonach wir uns zusehen**

Das aber ergibt für mich überhaupt keinen Sinn. Was hat der Nachrichtensprecher wirklich gesagt und was bedeutet es?

Comment: Und Freitags wünscht er einen "feinen Abend" anstatt "schönen Abend".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Er sagt:

> ...wie immer an dieser Stelle, Ihnen allen einen schönen Abend, **wo auch immer Sie uns zusehen.**

Unabhängig davon, wo sich die Zuschauer befinden, wünscht er allen einen schönen Abend.

Comment: Stimmt -- frisch aus dem Phrasendrescher.